# No Module named Slugify in Odoo 12

Tags: python, windows, odoo, odoo-12, slugify

I came across a module from GitHub and I went through the steps to install, but I am getting this error:

```
Unable to install module because an external dependency is not met: No module named slugify
```

However, Slugify is installed:

```
Requirement already satisfied: python-slugify in c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: text-unidecode==1.2 in c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from python-slugify->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.2)
```

I am using the following parameters for testing:

```
OS: Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit
Odoo 12.0-20181022 (Community Edition)
```

Can anyone please advise me where I failed?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: are you using source code, or executable ?

Comment: Slugify was installed via 'pip3 install python-slugify'

Comment: I mean Odoo, how do you run it

Comment: Odoo installed as git source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the same python virtual environment that Odoo uses and run:

```
try:
    import slugify
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import sys
    print("Module not found under the following directories: %s"%sys.path)
```

Comment: You are right. the error was that I installed slugify for another python environment. Now it's working fine. Many Thanks.